# dom document to get the href and nodeValue

Tags: php

I need to fetch the nodeValue and the HREF from this following snippet

```
<a class="head_title" href="/automotive/pr?sid=0hx">Automotive</a>
```

To achieve this I have done the following:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $p) {

    if($p->getAttribute('class') == 'head_title') {

        foreach($p->childNodes as $child) {
            $name = $child->nodeValue;

            echo $name ."<br />";
            echo $child->hasAttribute('href');  
        }

    }
  }
```

It returns me an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMText::hasAttribute()
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

hasAttribute is valid method for [DOMElements](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) but you cannot use it for text nodes. Can you check the type of node and then try to extract the value is its not a 'text' node. The following code might help you

```
foreach($p->childNodes as $child) {
   $name = $child->nodeValue;

   echo $name ."<br />";
   if ($child->nodeType == 1) {
       echo $child->hasAttribute('href');
   }  
}
```

It checks if the node is of type ['DOMElement'](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php) and invokes hasAttribute method only if it is a DOMElement.

Comment: @Diptendu...while doing the following coding:  foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $p) {

    if($p->getAttribute('class') == 'head_title') {
  
  foreach($p->childNodes as $child) {
   $name = $child->nodeValue;
   
   if ($child->nodeType == 1) {
       echo $child->hasAttribute('href');
   }  
      
  }
  
 }
  }  it gives me a blank page

Comment: Are you seeing any PHP Fatal error ? I could not test this since I don't have a PHP setup. Let me know if there is any way I can try this out on some fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...I did the changes in my coding like the following:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
if($link->getAttribute('class') == 'head_title') {

        $link2 = $link->nodeValue;
        $link1 = $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo  "<a href=".$link1.">".$link2."</a><br/>";
}
  }
```

And it works for me!